# Is a manifold $N$ smoothly embedded in a manifold $M$ of the same dimension open in $M$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Consider a manifold smooth manifold $N$ smoothly embedded in another manifold $M$ of the same dimension. Is it true that $N$ is open in $M$? I think this is true, due to the open mapping theorem.

If so, is this also true with less regularity?

Comment: What do you mean by "less regularity"?

Comment: For example, continuous embeddings, or worse, topological manifolds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true for topological manifolds (without boundary). This is a consequence of the *invariance of domain*. See for example

[Version of Invariance of Domain for n-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837092)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Given an embedding $f : N \to M$, each $x \in N$ has an open chart neighborhood $U$ which is mapped homeomorphically into an open chart neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$. Both $U,V$ are homeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence invariance of domain implies that $f(U)$ is open in $V$ and therefore open in $M$. Since $f(U) \subset f(N)$, we see that $f(N)$ is open in $M$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

A smooth immersion of one manifold into another of the same dimension is also a submersion. Submersions are open maps. Thus, the image of $N$ is open in $M$.

Comment: Proving that submersions are open maps is a good exercise, if this is something you’re not already familiar with.

Comment: About immersion implies submersion, can you help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298447/for-manifolds-of-the-same-dimension-are-submersions-equivalent-to-immersions) please?